# Select pods by label for use by Fluent Bit in Kubernetes DaemonSet

Tags: kubernetes

I have pods in Kubernetes with a label:

```
metadata:
  labels:
    fluentbit-loggable: true
```

I only want my Fluent Bit configuration to pick up those pods.

I followed [this great tutorial](https://echorand.me/posts/fluentbit-kubernetes/) on getting things set up, but I only have certain pods I want going to my destination. I don't have control over the applications (nor the pods, besides adding labels) so I figured there was a way to only have Fluent Bit use specific pods in the Kubernetes setup, but I couldn't find anything.

I'm going to Splunk, so I'm using [this output configuration](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/splunk) in order to get data there.

Anyone have a link to documentation on how to limit which pods to use or an example of selecting pods for the Fluent Bit DaemonSet via labels?

Comment: Hi `el n00b`, I am also looking for the same solution. Did you figure out one already?

Comment: @Aman I did not. I actually wound up using an alternative to this and put the different tokens for Splunk's HTTP ingress in my Helm charts and injecting it that way. That way things don't go since they don't have a token.